# Is there any way to integrate Java EE standard security with apache flex?

Tags: apache, security, apache-flex, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to integrate Java EE standard security with apache flex?

i.e. authentication, authorization, and access control over flex pages and form functions

Comment: No, Flex runs entirely on the client, thus there are no pages. You can only secure access to tthe application and service calls. The rest has to be handled by he client.